# Loop to obfuscate many android apps

Tags: java, android, python, obfuscation, android-proguard

For research purpose I need to test if my classifier is robust to obfuscation techniques.
My testing set is made of 25189 android apps from class A and 3175 from class B, with 20% apps already obfuscated.
I would like to obfuscate a certain amount of theses apps from 20% to 80% for example to plot the evolution of efficiency function of obfuscation %.
I have heard about proguard but couldn't figure out if it allow to loop over many apks.
I am using weka API for the classification process.

Is there a way to set up such obfuscation loop in Java, python, or with any software or frameworks ?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you running some command to do the obfuscation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the file names in python and obfuscate via whatever command you are using to do the obfuscation:

```py
import subprocess

apk_filenames = ['file1.apk', 'file2.apk', ...]

for apk in apk_filenames:
    subprocess.run(['your', 'command', 'here', apk])
```

Comment: It seems to be the way of doing it, and I like the fact that I could easily change the obfuscation technique from the command line.
Actually I just started to look on proguard so I don't have the "right" command line yet (Since I was looking for all possible solutions).
Before accepting your answer, are you familiar with obfuscation and know if proguard allows to work directly on the '.apk' files ?

Comment: @Vanpourix I'm unsure as to how proguard works sorry